# Accessing variables from one include inside another

Tags: php, scope, include

I have a PHP file called index.php and inside it I say:

```
include_once "settings.php";
include_once "autoload.php";
```

the settings.php file says, among other things:

```
$srcDir = "/home/blah.php";
```

then autoload.php has a function like this:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    echo "srcdir is: $srcDir";
}
```

But I get an error that $srcDir is not defined

Maybe there is a better OOP way of doing all this, but I am just using settings.php for setting file paths, and I could like it to be easy for editing by graphic designer in company, just simple file

Comment: Do you mean `$srcDir = "/home/blah.php";` (missed `$`)? As long as variables are defined in current scope they're visible by consecutively included scripts that access them in scope.

Comment: Oh that was just a typo by me on here, the $ is in there. Yeah I'm very confused as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: how about from the autoload function try file_get_contents('settings.php'); if it doesnt work then the file isnt being included. try that

Comment: or you can do print_r(get_included_files()); to see if the settings file is being loaded

Comment: How very odd - when I print the file_get_contents line, nothing appears, but the print_r get included files thing DOES show the settings.php file included. I even put that print_r thing INSIDE the function, and it shows the file included, but I still get the error. And the settings.php file itself is correct, it sets the variable and if I add an echo inside it to show me the variable, it works. HOW WEIRD

Comment: uhhh even if I add the variable declaration to just outside the autoload function, it doesn't work?!?

Comment: where did you declare `$srcDir` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the variable into function's scope.

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    global $srcDir;
    echo "srcdir is: $srcDir";
}
```

Comment: this is unnecessary, once you include a php file, it acts like that the code is appended where it was included.

Comment: @Euphoria http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php , 2nd example, "Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope".

Comment: This indeed makes it work. I'll have to read on it more because I don't full understand, but it works.